# Jenkins - 'Execute shell' marked build as failure

Tags: bash, selenium, jenkins

I am running selenium tests using python on Jenkins. I keep getting a build failure with the message 'Execute shell' marked build as failure and no errors. There is a post-build script which also fails afterwards. How can I get more information on why the build step fails and what could be causing it?

**pre-build commands**

```
aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-0c69e983f7523357a --count 1 --instance-type t3.micro --key-name Jenkins --subnet-id subnet-44c9b033 --output=json  | jq -r ".Instances[].InstanceId" > untagged.json

sleep 20

# Tag every instance in that file
< untagged.json xargs -I{} aws ec2 create-tags --resources {} --tag "Key=Purpose,Value=Selenium_BO_ReportViewer"

sleep 40
```

**build step commands**

```
#!/bin/bash 

cd automation-UI
export PROJECT_PATH=`pwd`
export PATH="$PROJECT_PATH:$PATH"

echo "-------------------------------------------"
echo "RUNNING TESTS"
echo "-------------------------------------------"
python3 -m pytest --cache-clear -W ignore -v -rA -s -m "reportviewer" -n 0 --tb=short --show-capture=no --runenv ci --reruns 1 --reruns-delay 2
```

**post-build commands**

```
# Since we are done, terminate the selenium slave we started in the first step
< untagged.json xargs -I{} aws ec2 terminate-instances --instance-ids {}
```

**console log**

````
09/09/2021 12:34:56AM - N/A - FieldFxTicketPage - test_rounding_numbers_in_ticket_report - INFO: grid table data reading

  0%|          | 0/3 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
 33%|███▎      | 1/3 [1:10:02<2:20:04, 4202.08s/it]Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
[PostBuildScript] - [INFO] Executing post build scripts.
[report-viewer] $ /bin/bash -xe /tmp/jenkins1788184406631893042.sh
+ xargs '-I{}' aws ec2 terminate-instances --instance-ids '{}'
xargs: aws: terminated by signal 15
[PostBuildScript] - [ERROR] An error occured during post-build processing.
org.jenkinsci.plugins.postbuildscript.PostBuildScriptException: java.lang.InterruptedException
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.postbuildscript.processor.Processor.processBuildSteps(Processor.java:190)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.postbuildscript.processor.Processor.processScripts(Processor.java:91)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.postbuildscript.processor.Processor.process(Processor.java:79)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.postbuildscript.processor.Processor.process(Processor.java:73)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.postbuildscript.PostBuildScript.perform(PostBuildScript.java:77)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:21)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:808)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:757)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:179)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:701)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1914)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:100)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:433)
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.waitFor(UNIXProcess.java:395)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.join(Proc.java:331)
    at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.join(CommandInterpreter.java:195)
    at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:145)
    at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:92)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.postbuildscript.processor.Processor.processBuildSteps(Processor.java:180)
    ... 13 more
Build step 'Execute scripts' marked build as failure
[WS-CLEANUP] Deleting project workspace...
[WS-CLEANUP] Skipped based on build state FAILURE
Finished: FAILURE```
````

Comment: The code you posted doesn't match the error message. The error happened on an `aws` command which isn't in your code. Its failing post-build, not build.

Comment: @jordanm please look carefully it says Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure just before the post build script runs. Error is happening during build step and also post build. I added the post build commands as well though

Comment: Have you tried adding any debugging, such as `--pdb` in your python3 cmd?

Comment: Your question is unclear to me as it was to @jordanm Can you first tell me if this is a pipeline or freestyle job, and if its a pipeline can you post the entire thing

Comment: @ChrisMaggiulli its a freestyle job. I have added the entire thing

Comment: If you run the xarg command in bash outside of Jenkins does it do what you expect?